# Load yaml files in nuxt-i18n

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js, nuxt-i18n

How do I load my locales from yaml files in Nuxt 2 using nuxt-i18n?

I already added the paths to my `nuxt.config.js`:

```js
{
  i18n: {
    vueI18nLoader: true,
    langDir: '~/locales/',
    locales: [
      { code: 'en', iso: 'en-GB', file: 'en.yaml', dir: 'ltr' },
      { code: 'de', iso: 'de-DE', file: 'de.yaml', dir: 'ltr' },
    ],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  }
}
```

I enabled vue-i18n-loader which brings automatic yaml support and i18n blocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Nuxt to use the [yaml-loader](https://github.com/eemeli/yaml-loader) for your locales:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
{
  // ...
  build: {
    // ...
    extend(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.ya?ml$/,
        type: 'json',
        use: 'yaml-loader'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Learn more about extending the Webpack configuration in Nuxt, here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-build#extend

This will allow you to load yaml files for [nuxt-i18n / vue-i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/). However, it will also clash with the custom [i18n block](https://i18n.nuxtjs.org/per-component-translations) (`<i18n>`) in your Vue components (given you use the SFC pattern).

To prevent this, you can change the above rule to only apply to yaml files in your `locales/` directory (or any other directory you would like):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
{
  // ...
  build: {
    // ...
    extend(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /locales\/.*\.ya?ml$/, // <---
        type: 'json',
        use: 'yaml-loader'
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Now you can use both i18n blocks as well as yaml files from your `locales/` directory.

Comment: At the end, if you're using `.yaml` files for your i18n, you should not really need to have local `i18n` tags inside of your SFC files anyway.

Comment: Don't forget to add yaml-loader with `npm install --save-dev yaml-loader`